# "autistic" vs "artistic" in RP

Tags: pronunciation, received-pronunciation

**How well do common variants of Received Pronunciation distinguish between "autistic" versus "artistic"?**

Wiktionary gives the distinction that the former uses for the leading syllable  the open-mid back rounded vowel whereas the latter uses the  open back unrounded vowel,
but it may be hard for many lacking strong familiarity with these designations to imagine just how clear the distinction is for   a listener.

Comment: If you're a Californian trying to distinguish between these pronunciations, good luck. If you've grown up speaking a dialect that distinguishes between these two vowels, they don't sound very similar.

Comment: @PeterShor - also the difference in meaning is sufficiently important that we probably say them distinctly differently. This avoids embarrassing misunderstandings.

Comment: _Autistic_ uses the vowel sound in _bawdy. Artistic_ (to a non-rhotic speaker) uses the vowel in _baa_ (imitation of sheep's bleat).

Comment: @KateBunting I've just tried them and realised that I purse my lips when saying "bawdy" or "autistic" and pull them back when saying "baa" or "artistic". But then we're both British.

Comment: @KateBunting As an AmE speaker, I use (I think) the same vowel for bawdy and baa. Can you explain how yours are different?

Comment: @StephenS - I think Bold Ben has explained this very clearly. To us, the sounds are very distinct.

Comment: RP is "the standard form of British English pronunciation, based on educated speech in southern England, widely accepted as a standard elsewhere." (Oxford Languages via Google) In RP, the distinction between autistic and artistic is clear and unmistakable. AE is not RP.

Comment: @Greybeard: in American English, the difference between *artistic* and *autistic* is also unmistakeable — there is an "r" in *artistic*. The problem comes when somebody speaking a non-rhotic dialect is talking to somebody with the COT-CAUGHT merger.

Comment: I'm sure your right, but, unless they have used "RP" wrongly...

Answer (score 2):

According to Wiktionary, in RP [*autistic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autistic) is /ɔːˈtɪs.tɪk/ and [*artistic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/artistic) is /ɑːˈtɪstɪk/. If you speak a dialect of American English with the *cot-caught merger* [(see Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger), you will have no phonemic contrast between these, so you may find it very difficult to hear the difference.

Comment: Let me add that if you don't speak a dialect with the *cot-caught* merger, it is quite easy to hear the difference.